# How can I send ActionMailer email to email from form input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I want a logged in user to be able to input their friend's email into a form input, click send and it will send a mailer to them. Here is what I have so far

mailer.rb

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: "donotreply@site.net"

 def invite(recipient_email, body, subject)
  @recipient_email = recipient_email
  @body = body
  mail(to: recipient_email, 
   body: body
   subject: 'Join me on this awesome site!')
  end
end
```

mailer_controller

```
class mailerController < ApplicationController

def new
end

 def create
  @recipient_email = params[:recipient_email]
  body = params[:invitation]
  Mailer.invitation(@recipient_email).deliver 
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Message sent'
  redirect_to root_url
 end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(new_invitation_url) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.input :recipient_email %>
<%= f.submit :invite %>
<% end %>
```

invite.html.erb

```
Mailer#invite
Check out this awesome site!

<%= new_user_url %>
```

routes.rb

```
post "invites/new" => "invite#create", as: :new_invite
```

Comment: You should define your Mailer#invite method to take in recipient email: def invite(recipient, invite, subject = 'Check out this site I found!'). Other than this what other problem are you facing?

Comment: I got it to send the email. But it is not capturing the :recipient_email from the form for the recipient_email in the controller. If I set the @recipient_email in the controller = to the email I want to send to, it works. How do I get the form :recipient_email into the controller#create recipient_email?